# Returning a specific amount of decimals in C

Tags: c, decimal

I am wondering how could I return a specific amount of decimals. My code is below and I want to return the value with only one decimal but I couldn't find the right syntax. (e.g x=3.465.. but I want to return x=3.4)

```
    double avg(int* grade, int len){
    int i; float sum=0.0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    sum+=*(grade+i);
    }

    return sum/len;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot return specific amount of decimals, unless you are return a numeric *string*. You probably mean rounding, but be aware that floating point numbers are stored in binary, so rounding to specific number of decimal digits won't be possible for all numbers.

Comment: It is not clear whether you need _rounding_ or _formatting_ or any of those. Please look up the difference, ask your teacher, clarify.

Comment: There is no machine floating point number that precisely equals 3.4. Perhaps you want to clarify what exactly your assignment means.

Comment: @moooeeeep I need formatting, not rounding.

Comment: @n.m. My assignment says the return value have only one digit after decimal point. For instance the example given in the assignment sheet was 50.0.

Comment: If your assignment **says** "only one digit after decimal point", in these or similar **words**,  then it is is not doable in this here universe, sorry. You can try to cheat the instructor and return a number which is approximately 3.3999999999999999112, which is the closest one to 3.4 you can get. If your assignment only **shows** one digit after decimal point, then you are inventing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are summing integers, you could multiply the average by 10 in the integer domain, and divide by 10 in the real domain.

```
double avg(int* grade, int len){
    int i; int sum=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        sum+=grade[i];
    }

    return (sum * 10 / len) / 10.0;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave but still it returns something like _A.B00000_ . Thank you.

Comment: @Zusaetlich but `A.B00000` is the same as `A.B`, isn't it?

Comment: There's no way in C to get a function to return specifically `A.B`; `A.B00000` is the closest you will get (and is exactly the same number anyway), unless you want to return a string rather than a float. Hell, you're not even returning `A.B00000`, you're returning a 32-bit value that is formatted as `A.B00000` on display

Answer (score 2):

Why?

Precision only matters when displaying it to the user; until that point, surely you should use the highest degree of precision available?

To format a float in something like a printf statement, use `%3.1f` - field width of 3, 1 number after the decimal point.

Comment: Because I was asked by teacher in my C assignment. Will I use the statement you gave in return part?

Comment: What specifically does the assignment say? Does it say to *return* a value, or to *print* a value?

Comment: It says the answer should have 1 digit after decimal point and we are only allowed to write functions, they do the print part.  So if I understand correct, I have to return a value.

Comment: Right, I see - in which case, Ian Abbott's solution should do what you need, and the most efficiently to boot.

Answer (score -1):

To make things more dynamic, it is possible to do the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double trunc_dec(double number, unsigned char length) {
    int mult = pow(10, length);
    return trunc(number * mult) / mult;
}

int main() {
    printf("%f\n", trunc_dec(15.234, 1));
}
```